# Timer em PHP chamando function

Tags: php, timer

Alguém tem um exemplo simples de um timer em *PHP*, que chame uma função a cada tempo predeterminado.
Por exemplo, para checar se já chegou uma determinada hora ou data/hora.

Comment: Poste o código que você já fez até o momento!

Comment: Dependendo do seu objetivo não é possível, pois PHP precisa de um gatilho para ser executado. Pois sem star em execução um script não faz nada, precisaria do timer ser feito ou no crontab, ou com javascript. Por que em PHP puro iria precisar de refresh para verificar o tempo

Comment: Poderia contextualizar melhor a sua pergunta?

Comment: Depende, você quer executar algo em background, ou quer que quando chegar determinada hora, o php envie algo para o browser?

Comment: É para diversas funções, como atualizar uma data/hora, montar um contador de tempo regressivo, verificar se o banco de dados foi alterado.

Comment: @OrlandoFMC qual servidor ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer uso do [`crontab`](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Usando-cron-e-crontab-para-agendar-tarefas), basta definir o horário e o arquivo `php` que que chamar; por exemplo:

```
*  *  * * *   root    php /path/file.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Esse script vai rodar a cada minuto, e todos os dias, pelo usuário root, abaixo vou deixar uma imagem auto explicativa do uso do cromtab;

> O `>/dev/null 2>&1` joga toda saida do *limbo*, forma simples de não ficar imprimindo na tela retornos do script.

[image: CROMTAB]

Existem outras formas de utilizar, por exemplo com o [Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/358462/agendamento-de-tarefas-e-publica%C3%A7%C3%A3o/358473#358473);

Comment: Uma observação: se a resposta for essa, a pergunta é duplicata. Já tem várias no site falando de crontab e agendador de tarefas (note que a pergunta está abandonada desde 2016).

Comment: Sim eu percebi após responder, vi que avia sido atualizada hoje, com relação ao crontab eu não vejo forma mais pratica do que essa.